# Document Manager Recommendations

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, jdocument

I'm looking for some recommendations for a document manager that's compatible with Joomla 3+. Seems to be a pretty popular question throughout the Joomla community.

In the past I've always used [Phoca Download](https://www.phoca.cz/joomla3demo/phoca-download-demo), it's worked well but I'm thinking of trying something new as I think it's looking a bit dated.

I've been reading about [Docman by Joomlatools](https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/docman/). I can't see it in the JED - any idea why this is? I've read some [forum posts](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=957570&f=715#p3528601) about their license and how people have had issues with it so I'm slightly skeptical.

There's also [eDocman by JoomDonation](https://www.joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/edocman-joomla-download-manager.html) - I know nothing about this but it seems pretty good. It's also in the JED.

[DropFiles](https://www.joomunited.com/products/dropfiles) seems pretty new and it's lacking some features that the others have. I do like the design,though.

My requirements for a document manager are;

- responsive
- allow user uploads
- multiple categories and subcategories
- access control

I don't mind paying for the right / best component.

Comment: If the only problem for Phoca download is its 'look' why don't just doing a template override?

Comment: @webchun Because i'd rather not. I'd prefer this was already implemented. Creating overrides for every site I maintain is a big task, especially as they use different templates, layouts and frameworks.

Comment: At a recent local user group meeting Nicky V. presented a case study and documentation management was a big part of the project and she had reviewed those listed above and went with eDocman by JoomDonation. So a secondhand thumbs up for that one.

Comment: @Irata I have used several extensions made by joomdonation in the past. Their extensions are good in terms of function but the looks is just average/standard. I ended up by overriding the template to get a more attractive look, and fortunately their base code is clean enough/easy to understand and easy to override. From the options jonboy proposed above, if 'looks' is the deciding factor, then it seems like dropfiles is better, if Docman doesn't count.

Comment: Perhaps this is more of an opinion based question? Although it seems popular i'm happy if the admins want to close?

Comment: This question has received a flag indicating that a reader feels that this page is opinion-based.  I partly agree.  Perhaps the remedy is to remove the subjective requirement: "user friendly". The remaining requirement can be objectively satisfied, no?